# Why does mapStateToProps return an array as a proxy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have my state updated and want to map it to props.

The strange thing is, that I can see the state is a list (as normal), however, when mapped to props, the props becomes a proxy.

The following code show the reducer which update the state of fitslist:

```
const initialState={
    fitslist:[]
}
const downloadFitsReq=(state=initialState,action)=>{
switch(action.type){
    case FITSSELECTED:
        console.log("fits selected");
        state={...state,fitslist:action.selectedRowKeys};
        console.log("selectedRowKeys: "+action.selectedRowKeys)
        console.log(state);
        return state
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Now I can see the state is updated and showing the list as expected:

```
{fitslist: Array(1)}
    fitslist:["1"]
    __proto__:Object
```

But when I map the state to props, the strange thing happens here:

```
const QueryFormMSTP=(state)=>{
    return {
        fitsClicked: state.downloadFitsReq.fitslist,
        form:state.form,
    }
};
const QueryFormC=connect(QueryFormMSTP,QueryFormMDTP)(QueryForm);
```

Now the `fitsClicked` becomes a proxy. `console.log` shows the following information of `fitsClicked`:

```
Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ,     isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}
```

I don't understand why. Can anyone help me, I have spent a whole day working on this problem. Thanks in advance.

The `mapDispatchToProps` function is as follows:

```
function QueryFormMDTP(dispatch,ownProps){
    return {
        downloadFits:(fitsClicked)=>{
            console.log("download clicked");
            console.log(fitsClicked);
            var fitsparam={
                fitsdownloadparam:fitsClicked
            };
            console.log(fitsparam);
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/work003-1.0/alma3/downloadFits',fitsparam)
                .then(function(fitsRes){
                    console.log(fitsRes);
                })
                .catch(e=>console.log(e))
        },
    }
};
```

If I change `console.log(fitsClicked)` to `console.log(ownProps.fitsClicked)`, it will show undefined.

The prop are declared in the Component part as follows:

```
QueryForm.propTypes={
    downloadFits:PropTypes.func,
    fitsClicked:PropTypes.array,
}
```

Comment: Where is mapStateToProps in your code? I don’t see that and are you using Redux connect?

Comment: The following code are the mapstatetoprop function:       `const QueryFormMSTP=(state)=>{
        return {
            //fitsSelectedp:state.sendAlmaQuery.selectedRowKeys,
            fitsClicked: state.downloadFitsReq.fitslist,
            form:state.form,
        }
    };`

Comment: Can you also post your initialstate code?

Comment: const initialState={
    fitslist:[]
} sorry that I am not familiar with markdown format

Comment: looks like proxies are because of ES6. Can you try with normal function instead of arrow function like function QueryFromMSTP(state){ return {fitsClicked: state.downloadFitsReq.fitslist}}

Comment: One more thing try removing form:state.form in your QueryFromMSTP and then try

Comment: @HemadriDasari yes, the ES6 grammer might be the problem and I tried it just now, but failed :( , the form:state.form can not be removed as it is required by ant-design library which my form used

Comment: which `console.log` results in the above o/p ? is it `console.log(this.props.fitsClicked)` ? where do you call it ?

Comment: interesting point, The console.log above is console.log(fitsClicked) in MapDispatchToProps function. I had added it in the post. When I changed that to console.log(ownProps.fitsClicked), it prints out undefined.... I feel more confused, I think mapdispatchtoprops can get the updated props returned by mapstatetoprops function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in mapStateToProps or in reducer also

```
const downloadFitsReq=(state=initialState,action)=>{
switch(action.type){
    case FITSSELECTED:
        console.log("fits selected");
        state={...state,fitslist:action.selectedRowKeys||[]};    //Note
        console.log("selectedRowKeys: "+action.selectedRowKeys)
        console.log(state);
        return state
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

OR in **QueryFormMSTP**

```
const QueryFormMSTP=(state)=>{
    return {
        fitsClicked: state.downloadFitsReq.fitslist || [],//Note
        form:state.form,
    }
};
const QueryFormC=connect(QueryFormMSTP,QueryFormMDTP)(QueryForm);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the fitslist can get the correct array from action's payload, however in QueryFormMSTP, fitsClicked returned is a proxy, add the`||[ ]` make no difference on the fitsClicked value.

Comment: I did't involve any action in QueryFormMDTP function just test if the props fitsClicked get the correct array.